# TinyMCE Add Menu Issue (with plugin)

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce-4

I've been trying to add my own menu and must be doing something wrong.  Here is what i have so far which is very simply a shell from some example code:

tinymce.html - page where I host the textarea and the init code:

```
<!-- /TinyMCE -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
   tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "textareas",
  skin: "o2k7",
  theme: "advanced",
  plugins: "mymenu,fullpage,safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
  theme_advanced_buttons1: "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
  theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
  theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
  theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
  toolbar: "mymenu",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
  theme_advanced_resizing: false,
  extended_valid_elements: "a[name|href|target|title|onclick],img[class|src|border=0|alt|title|hspace|vspace|width|height|align|onmouseover|onmouseout|name],hr[class|width|size|noshade],font[face|size|color|style],span[class|align|style]"
});
</script>
<!-- /TinyMCE -->

<body>
  <form method="post">
      <textarea name="tinyMceEditor" cols="1" rows="1" style="width:100%; height: 100%"></textarea>
  </form>
</body>
```

You can see the plugin 'mymenu' and the toolbar 'mymenu' are in the initialization of TinyMCE.

For the plugin, it is in the /Plugins/mymenu/ directory with the editor_plugin.js convention.  I know it is loading it because if I introduce an error to the file I get a warning.

editor_plugin.js:

```
(function() {
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.mymenu', {

    init: function (editor, url) {

        editor.addButton('mymenu', {
            type: 'menubutton',
            text: 'My Menu',
            icon: false,
            menu: [{
                text: 'Data Loop',
                onclick: function(){
                    editor.insertContent('{DataLoop}');
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Collector Loop',
                onclick: function(){
                    editor.insertContent('{CollectorLoop}');
                }

            }]

        });

    }
});

// Register plugin
tinymce.PluginManager.add('mymenu', tinymce.plugins.PageBreakPlugin);

})();
```

It looks to me like I have everything correct.  However - no menu shows up.  Just the 4 toolbar buttons as shown with buttons1-4 in the init code.

***Edit***:  I have tried removing all the advanced buttons, changing the theme to simple, and quite a few other options.  Still unable to get this simple menu to appear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows implementing an entire custom menu with two items in the menu:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/JDfaab

You don't have to create a plugin to implement custom menu items or toolbar buttons - you can do so directly in your configuration object.  If you really want a plugin you can take this example and move it to your own plugin.

Comment: I used this fiddle and put it directly into the init portion of the HTML file.  Still doesn't show a menu :(

Comment: Can you make a TinyMCE fiddle of what you are doing?

Comment: That's the thing... I have no problem doing it in CodePen like this:  http://codepen.io/bdogi/pen/KNRaVm.  When I do this in an HTML file, I get a blanked out but large textarea.  No menu.

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's JavaScript console?  What version of TinyMCE are you using?

Comment: Nothing in the Console tab at all.  I'm using 3.1.01, it looks like.  I just opened the changelog.log file and that is the last entry.  I just use Nuget to install and that's what it installed.

Comment: So TinyMCE 3.1 is well over 5 years old - the current product is 4.5 so I suspect you are trying to use TinyMCE 4 configuration data for TinyMCE 3.1 and that won't work.  Don't know how to use Nuget but there has to be a newer release than 3.1 available there.

Comment: I think you are right.  When I used Nuget, it actually said version 4.5 (I just checked what was installed and that is what it says).  I will refactor with 4.5 by  manual install instead.  Thanks and I will mark your answer as correct - because I have gotten things to work with 4.5